# Use of part perfect continuous vs. Past Perfect

Tags: grammar

If the Past Perfect Continuous tense is for an action in the past that keeps continuing, then why do we use the Past Perfect in the phrase:

> She mentioned that she had missed several movies because of Paul's late arrivals.

The action of missing the films is continuous.

Comment: I think it's to do with the fact that you've "quantified" the number of missed movies (albeit "loosely") by including ***several***. Without that, it would be perfectly idiomatic to say *She mentioned that she **had been missing** movies because of Paul's late arrivals*, but Past Perfect Continuous simply doesn't work very well with ***several***. Maybe that's not the whole story though, because ***some*** is also a "loose quantifier", but I can't see anything particularly odd about *She mentioned that she had been missing **some** movies because of Paul's late arrivals*.

Comment: Maybe it's that ***several*** suggests there ***is*** an actual "total" value for "missed movies" (which value is effectively "fixed", and no longer subject to change, so it can't really be part of an ongoing process where the total might continue to change). Whereas ***some*** could be seen as reflecting a ***ratio / percentage***, akin to, say, ***half of the movies*** - which again would work fine with the continuous verb form (if she continues to miss half of them; the ratio doesn't change).

Comment: No, in the sentence the action of missing is not continuous. It could be,but it is not.

Comment: I'm with Lambie on this. I'm not quite sure I understand the student's logic at all. If the Continuous is for an action that keeps continuing, and the sentence does not use the Continuous, then certainly from that they must conclude that the action is *not* continuous.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Regardless of the exact meaning of ***to miss** [movies]* here (which *might* affect the choice of verb form), wouldn't you agree if an *exact number* of movies is specified, this can make a big difference? *She had **been missing five** movies because of him* is at least "awkward" to parse, but without the actual *number*, it's a perfectly natural utterance. And I think more imprecise quantifiers such as "several, some, a few" are also affected by the ***had missed / had been missing*** verb choice in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have misinterpreted what is needed to be continuous in this sentence. That is, the list of movies must be continuous.

This sentence only reflects on a finite number of movies in the past that were missed, but makes no indication that there might be more movies that she didn't miss:

> She mentioned that she ***had missed several movies*** because of Paul's later arrivals.

***had missed*** => that's the end of the discussion.

By using the *past perfect continuous* instead, the implication is that the action of missing these movies has ceased, with the expectation that there are definitely more movies and she has not missed those ones.

> She mentioned that she ***had been missing several movies*** because of Paul's later arrivals.

***had been missing*** => but now she isn't, or but later she wasn't.

Comment: I think there's a significant difference between OP's ***She missed [some] movies*** (she didn't get to see them) and your ***She is missing [some] movies*** (she doesn't have them in her collection).

Comment: The difference pointed out here between had missed and had been missing is **spot on**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _**to miss**_ could imply more things here, too. Maybe she had established a particular relationship with the movies and yearned for their return. I chose to explore the meaning of the verb that made the most sense in the context. It is your assumption that I intended for her to be missing them from a collection, when in fact when I rewrote it with past perfect continuous, I had imagined an event with many movies currently playing and that she was unable to see them (i.e. she had been actively missing them).

Comment: I never assumed you had *any* specific meanings in mind (I never even thought of that "rueful reminiscing over things past" sense until your comment). And I did upvote your answer before posting my comment, so you shouldn't interpret it as a criticism. I just thought it was a relevant distinction that some learners might not recognise unless it was explicitly pointed out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know. I just wanted to be clear that your interpretation is not the one I meant. No offence intended.